# oracle form 6i closing window from cross button

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

When I close the window from cross button it popup for do you want to save the changes you have made as I know I can use button with this code

```
EXIT_FORM(NO_VALIDATE, NO_COMMIT);
```

but if user close form from cross button it popups what I did

```
WHEN-WINDOW-CLOSED
EXIT_FORM(NO_VALIDATE, NO_COMMIT);
```

but it didn't work why I need I have some information which triggered on `WHEN-NEW-FORM-INSTANCE`.

So if user commit save some data must be saved which I don't want to save.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, `EXIT_FORM` accepts none, one or two parameters, which are:

- exit_form
- exit_form (commit_mode)
- exit_form (commit_mode, rollback_mode)

You used the 3rd option with two parameters, but - both of them belong to the **commit mode** (which are `ask_commit`, `do_commit`, `no_commit`, `no_validate`).

Maybe Forms got confused by such values and prompted the user nonetheless. I suggest you try with just one of them, e.g. `no_validate` as it will

> exit the current form without validating the changes, committing the changes, or prompting the operator

---

By the way, saying

> if user commit save some data must be saved which I don't want to save.

doesn't make sense to me. It is **user** who should decide whether to save changes, not you. If you, as a developer, want to take control over it, create validation triggers (`WHEN-VALIDATE-ITEM`, `WHEN-VALIDATE-RECORD`) and - if there's something wrong, raise an error.

Comment: Thanks dear for your kind reply i did separately on when windows closed exit_form(no_commit) but results are same i have some initial values which are on forms so if user goes through exit button then it is controlled but if user closed through cross button then it asks for savings

Comment: as just we can change SDI windows button to closed allowed to :NO can we change MDI button to no?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks little foot i appreciate you every time respond to me I got answer
What i did in simple is that i did SDI Window -Closed allowed :No
and windows style change Document to Dialog 
and i get what i need 
again thanks for your kind response

Comment: I'm glad you made it work. Thank you for letting us know.

Comment: thanks Littlefoot you are Godfather of Oracle you helped more peoples anyone else on any forum where oracle developers needs you, You were there. Thanks for you lot of effort you made for the needy my pray with you stay blessed and  God gives you more happiness in life

Comment: Thank you; you're very kind :)